# Can you use an AND statement in a JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose you have two tables A and B and you are trying to write a JOIN query, is the following possible:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 
FROM A JOIN B on (A.col2 = B.col2 AND B.col3 = 'hello')
```

Will this return a table of col1 from table A and col2 from table B where there is a match in the second column across the tables and the third column of table B is 'hello'?

I.e. it will only return rows that are matching in col2 and this is further reduced to the cases where col3 in table B is 'hello'?

Comment: . . How else might you interpret the query?  I cannot think of any other way to interpret it, so I don't understand where your question is coming from.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the second condition should be put in a WHERE statement

Comment: yes, for an inner join a condition in the `ON` clause acts the same as one in the `WHERE` clause. It is clearer to put it in the `WHERE` clause though when it only references one table involved in the join. i.e. ``SELECT A.col1, B.col1 FROM A JOIN B on A.col2 = B.col2 WHERE B.col3 = 'hello'``

Comment: When it comes to OUTER JOINs, you have to be more careful when choosing ON or WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use:

1. Below will Join the Records in B table (Col3='hello') with A:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 
FROM A JOIN B on (A.col2 = B.col2 AND B.col3 = 'hello')
```

2. Below will Join all Records in B table with A, And performing where at Result of A and B:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 
FROM A JOIN B on A.col2 = B.col2
WHERE B.col3 = 'hello'
```

Both will give the same result when no other tables joined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You can specify any kind of boolean condition in the `ON` clause.

It is not mandatory that any column is involved in the condition so all of the following are valid:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 FROM A JOIN B on 1=1
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 FROM A JOIN B on B.col3 = 'hello'
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 FROM A JOIN B on (A.col2 = B.col2 AND B.col3 = 'hello')
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 FROM A JOIN B on (A.col2 = B.col2 AND B.col3 = C.col3)
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 FROM A LEFT JOIN B on (C.col3 = 'bye')
```

But pay attention, if you limit the condition to only key fields the optimizer engine will improve the performances very much.

Answer (score 0):

For an *inner join*, these two statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 
FROM A JOIN
     B 
     ON A.col2 = B.col2 AND B.col3 = 'hello';
```

and:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col1 
FROM A JOIN
     B 
     ON A.col2 = B.col2 
WHERE B.col3 = 'hello';
```

Both should have the same execution plans as well.

Some people prefer putting filtering conditions in the `WHERE` clause, so the query is more clear about "conditions between tables" versus "filters on the result set".  I tend to agree with this sentiment, although I'm not dogmatic about it.

`OUTER JOIN`s are different.  For an outer join, it makes a big different where the conditions go.  In that case, you generally do not have a choice, so you use `ON` or `WHERE` to get the logic that you want.